# Preferred Contact Method on Lead/Contact?

Tags: contact, leads

I need to assign a preferred contact method(email/phone/etc) to a Lead and Contact(after the lead gets converted). Is there a standard field/object that holds that information or should I create a new custom field?

I am going through the documentation right now but so far I can't find anything.

Comment: All **standard** fields on Contact can be found on its [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=contacts_fields.htm&type=5). Anything not available there has to be a custom field.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought but now I see there's a new object being introduced called UserEmailPreferredPerson so I thought there might be something similar for a preferred contact method.